# Should bundle from intent be cached to saved instance state bundle?

Tags: android

If activity A starts activity B and activity A passes a bundle to activity B in the intent when starting activity B, and activity B needs to access the bundle data on state changes, does this require activity B to cache the bundle data to the saved instance state, or will the bundle data be accessible via the intent? Basically, should the bundle from the intent be cached to the bundle of the saved instance state?

[Passing data from one activity to another using bundle - not displaying in second activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445182/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-using-bundle-not-displaying-in-secon)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is that the intent is preserved on activity recreation

[Android - Is the intent preserved during activity recreation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414093/android-is-the-intent-preserved-during-activity-recreation)